# Get UIBarButtonItem image position relative to its navigation bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have a sketch interface prototype from which I can get coordinates of UI elements. When I created bar button with image it was placed to default position on navigation bar. Code below:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
```

This default position differs from desired position. Is it possible to figure out that default image position (frame) relative to its navigation bar
[(white rect on this screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGgwA.png) without making a custom button? I need it to move image a little bit left but I don't want to do it visually with approximate offset.

Comment: can you post screen shot ?

Comment: @KetanP, I've added screenshot link to question.

Comment: You need to provide more details of your code and specify better what kind of solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access current navigation bar item view by using KVC

```
UIView *leftBarButtonItemView = [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use edge insets
For button text title:

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0);
```

For button with image:

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0);
```

Or if you want to move button horizontally only:

```
UIBarButtonItem *spaceButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[spaceButtonItem setWidth:-3]; // to move on the left
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[spaceButtonItem, leftButton];
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about the methods for moving bar button, but the question is about getting image (not bar button) position. Because with this methods I only can try some offset values until the moment when position will look good. But how can I know that I placed image at the same point as it described in mockup?